# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when pushing values to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a hash with an array inside:

```
# create new hash to store customers and their projects
@customers = Hash.new

# get all customers from Mite
Mite::Customer.all.each do |customer|
  @customers[customer.id] = {:name => customer.name, :projects => []}
end

# get all projects from Mite and store them in the :projects array
Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
  @customers[project.customer_id][:projects] << project # line 17
end
```

`Mite::Project.all` and `Mite::Customer.all` are methods for an external API (mite.yo.lk). They work and i get data back, so thats not the failure.

Unfortunately, i have to go this way, cause the API doesn't have any methods to filter projects by the customer id.

That's the error message:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:17:in `block in index'
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:16:in `each'
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:16:in `index'
```

I don't understand whats wrong here?

Comment: is app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:17 == @customers[project.customer_id][:projects] << project

Comment: could it be possible your data is inconsistent and there are projects related to not existing customers?

Comment: @Nazar Yes. Sorry, forgot to mark the correct line

Comment: @thorstenmüller no, the data is correct. projects MUST have an active customer

Comment: Just because it looks like @customers[project.customer_id] returns nil, since it's complaining about [] not about <<. What do you see in the logger if you output @customers?

Comment: And just because there is a value in customer_id does not mean this customer does actually exist as a record.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I figured out a mistake in the API: I get one project without active customer. All other projects with inactive customers are not displayed, except this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what @thorstenmüller said is correct. Looks like the Projects contains references to stale customers?

I would recommend defensive coding, provided it does not introduce logical errors. Something like:

```
# get all projects from Mite and store them in the :projects array
Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
  if @customers[project.customer_id].present?
    @customers[project.customer_id] << project
  end
end
```

Again, I would only recommend this if stale customers are acceptable in your database.

Another thing to look out for is that project.customer_id is a consistant type (i.e. always an Integer or String):

```
# get all customers from Mite
Mite::Customer.all.each do |customer|
  @customers[customer.id.to_i] = {:name => customer.name, :projects => []}
end
```

and

```
# get all projects from Mite and store them in the :projects array
Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
  @customers[project.customer_id.to_i][:projects] << project # line 17
end
```

I have personally been caught out on this far too many times.

HTH and best.

Comment: Thanks for your defensive coding recommendation!

I figured it out: There is a mistake in the API: I get one project without active customer. All other projects with inactive customers are not displayed, except this one...

Answer (score 1):

If it is not acceptable that a customer is not defined, you could raise a more specific error, which tells you which customer is missing:

```
Mite::Project.all.each do |project|
  begin
    @customers[project.customer_id].fetch(:projects) << project
  rescue IndexError => error
    raise(error.class, "customer missing: #{project.customer_id}", error.backtrace)
  end
end
```

An alternative is to create the customer instead of re-raising the error.